# Centos Laravel Permission denied how to change permissions?

Tags: nginx, centos

Hi there my centos machine returns permission error when try to work.

"The stream or file "/usr/share/nginx/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied"

I tried;

```
 chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html
 chown -R root:root /usr/share/nginx/html
 chown -R root:root /usr/share/nginx/html/*
 chown -R nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/*
 chown -R $USER:$USER /usr/share/nginx/html
 sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/share/nginx/html/storage
 chmod -R 775 storage/framework
chmod -R 775 storage/framework
chmod -R 775 storage/logs
```

But nothing changed. What could be wrong?
How can I learn "which user should I give permission"?

Comment: Could you please run command like: `ls -ld /usr/share/nginx/html/storage/logs/laravel.log` and post output here then.

Answer (score 3):

```
# if group is nginx then
# owner is root
chown -R root:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html

# any files/folder created will inherit permission of the group of the parent
chmod -R 2755 /usr/share/nginx/html

# if already there are some folder and file
# we're changing permission here

# directory permission
find /usr/share/nginx/html -type d -exec chmod 2755 {} \;

# file permission
find /usr/share/nginx/html -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

# nginx group can write logs
# group nginx can read-write-execute for logs
# you can use same if you're having cache/upload directory 

setfacl -R -m g:nginx:rwx /usr/share/nginx/html/storage/logs
```

###### IF `SELINUX` Enabled then

```
# default 
semanage fcontext -a  -t httpd_sys_content_t '/usr/share/nginx/html(/.*)?'

# Here we make persistent changes in semanage fcontext for log path
# now httpd can write log  
semanage fcontext -a  -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/usr/share/nginx/html/storage/logs(/.*)?'

# restore selinux context
restorecon -Rv '/usr/share/nginx/html/storage/logs(/.*)?'
```